# Trying to write my own compare to method for strings - Java

Tags: java, string-comparison

[EDIT]: I've rewritten everything, I find a much simpler way by starting to put both of my arrays in capital letters, it was way easier for the comparisons ! Thanks for your help :)

I'm a beginner on java, and I have to write my own `compareTo()` method to compare lexicographically to strings. For instance, `"hello"` and `"hello"` should give same while `"hello"` and `"hello world"` should give s2>s1. In case of capital letter, the comparison is suppose to return same, for example "HeLLo" and " hELlo" should give same, but as I'm using the ASCII values, I have a lot of trouble figuring this out. Finally, the strings can also be of different lengths.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
public class compare
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
String s1 = "HHzllozz";
String s2 = "LLLLLLellozzzzzzz";

//System.out.println(s1.length()); --> just here to check
//System.out.println(s2.length());

char char1; 
char char1b;

char char2;
char char2b;

int index = 0;
int compNb = 0; //--> keep track of the nb of comparisons done

if (s1.length()<s2.length())
{
  compNb = s1.length();
}
else
{
  compNb = s2.length();
}

System.out.println(compNb);

for(int i=0; i<compNb; i++)
{  
  char1 = s1.charAt(i);
  char1b = s1.toUpperCase().charAt(i);

  char2 = s2.charAt(i);
  char2b = s2.toUpperCase().charAt(i);

  int ascii1 = (int) char1;
  int ascii2 = (int) char2;



  if (s1.length()>s2.length())
  {
    for( int j = 0; j<s2.length(); j++)
    {
      if(ascii1 > ascii2)
      {
        index = 1;
        break;
      }
      else if(ascii1 < ascii2)
      {
        index = -1;
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        index = 1; 
      }
    }
  }

  if(s1.length()<s2.length())
  {
    for(int j = 0; j<s2.length(); j++)
    {
      if(ascii1 > ascii2)
      {
        index = 1;
        break;
      }
      else if(ascii1 < ascii2)
      {
        index = -1;
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        index = -1; 
      }
    }
  }
  if(s1.length() == s2.length())
  {

    if(ascii1 > ascii2)
    {
      index = 1;
      break;
    }
    else if(ascii1 < ascii2)
    {
      index = -1;
      break;
    }
    else if(s1.charAt(i) == s2.charAt(i) || s1.charAt(i) == s2.toUpperCase().charAt(i) || s2.charAt(i) == s1.toUpperCase().charAt(i))
    {
      index ++;

    }

  }
  //System.out.println(s1.charAt(i) + " value : "+ ascii1);
  //System.out.println(s2.charAt(i) + " value : " + ascii2);
}

System.out.println(index);

if (index == compNb && compNb !=1)
{
  System.out.println("same");
}
if(index == 1)
{
  System.out.println("S1>s2");      
}
if(index == -1)
{
  System.out.println("s2>s1");      
}
  }

}
```

It work for some case but not for all of them, I honestly am kind of lost on this one. For example in the case presented above, it shows s1>s2, which is not the case.

Comment: can you provide a few more examples to help understand your question

Comment: First, I'd start with writing the formal `compareTo` method, not have it buried all in `main`.

Comment: Similar to V_Singh's comment... I recommend splitting this into 2 sub-tasks.  BOTTOM-UP - learn the String and character APIs by playing with them (read javadocs, write test programs, etc).  TOP-DOWN - break down the problem statement into parts until you know how to solve every part with what you know from the Bottom-up learning.  For example, look around for ways to compare or change the case of a character (e.g. String.toUpperCase), then create a solution using that so the comparison can be done in a case-insensitive manner.

Answer (score 0):

First of all- you below statement is little confusing. Can you clarify that:

> In case of capital letter, the comparison is suppose not suppose to change, but as i'm using the ascii values, I have a lot of trouble figuring this out.

Your logic also appears very complicated. You should try to simplify it something like this. Understand and define your solution first and then jump into coding. I'm putting a solution in plain english, but its very easy to code:

To compare 2 strings s1 and s2, define rules like these and just implement them:

1. If length of s1 is greater than length of s2, return 1 (or in your case s1>s2).
2. If length of s2 is greater than length of s1, return -1 (or in your case s2>s1).
3. If the lengths are same, then compare their characters one by one and break at any step where the ascii values of those don't match. Return s1>s2 if ascii value of character of s1 is bigger, else return s2>s1.

Of course, you have to put checks for null values in the beginning to avoid any undue exceptions in your method.

---

**[Based on OP's update of question]**

If you just want to return the answer based on rank of the strings lexicographically, then you need not check for lengths of the strings. Just do the following:

1. Make the strings case agnostic by changing all the letters to lowercase or uppercase for both strings.
2. Create 2 char arrays for both strings and iterate over them sequentially checking for equality, something like this (I'm using java APIs for uppercase conversion and converting strings to char arrays, you can write you own if you like):

   `String s1 = string1.toUppercase();
   String s2 = string2.toUppercase();
   char[] s1Array = s1.toCharArray(); //confirm exact API or write your method
   char[] s1Array = s1.toCharArray();
   int lengthToConsider = (s1Array.length < s2Array.length) ? s1Array.length : s2Array.length;
   for(int i=0; i<lengthToConsider; i++)'
   {
      if( s1Array[i] < s2Array[i] )
      {
        return "s2>s1";
      }
      else if( s1Array[i] > s2Array[i] )
      {
         return "s1>s2";
      }
   }
   // if you reach here, that means all letters compared earlier are same
   if(s1Array.length > s2.length)
   {
     return "s1>s2";
   }
   else if(s1Array.length < s2.length)
   {
     return "s2>s1";
   }
   else
   {
      return "equal";
   }`

Comment: I've edited my post. But I don't want my program to compare only their length, but I want it to compare them lexicographically, like which string would be the first if we were looking for it in a dictionary ! Thanks !

Comment: I've updated my answer to cater to your requirement. You are not looking at the lengths in the beginning, just comparing the letters one by one. And if they are still same, then checking for lengths. So 'HELLO' will be smaller than 'Hellor'.